# ASP.NET API call with decryption

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-apicontroller

Is there a way in which I can apply logic prior to an API call in .net?

Example:

```
// PUT: api/TodoItems/5
[HttpPut("{id}")]    
public async Task<IActionResult> PutTodoItem(long id, TodoItem todoItem)
{
 //...
}
```

If I send a TodoItem to this point that is serialized as JSON there is no issue. But what if I want to encrypt the TodoItem before sending and decrypt prior to this method call?

I can see an alternative that would be the following logic:

1. Serialize TodoItem to JSON string
2. Encrypt TodoItemJSONstring
3. Send PUT request with encrypted TodoItemJSONstring
4. Unencrypt in PutTodoItem(long id, string todoItem) - **note signature change**
5. Deserialize

Is there a way of doing this that does not require a signature change, where I can apply the decryption before the JSON string is deserialized?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Nothing to do with Entity-Framework btw...

Comment: 1) you can use HTTPS, in fact, almost everybody expects sites to use HTTPS. Why add extra encryption instead of using HTTPS with TLS1.2+ ? 2) you can write your own middleware for ASP.NET MVC/Web API and ASP.NET Core

Comment: That's even easier than what I was thinking @PanagiotisKanavos and seems to be the better solution to my problem.

Comment: What are you trying to protect against? If you use custom encryption, how is the *client* going to decrypt it? You have to agree and set up an encryption scheme, exchange certificates or secrets. If the client is a browser, extra encryption is pointless. Check [Do I need additional encryption on top of HTTPS for a REST API?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/178315/do-i-need-additional-encryption-on-top-of-https-for-a-rest-api)

Comment: The ASP.NET Core project templates configure HTTPS by default. Check [Enforce HTTPS in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) for details, possible extra configurations (eg about HSTS), what to avoid to ensure you don't send unencrypted data by accident, and how to handle certificates in development and production

Comment: I didn't add this information in the question because I didn't feel it was pertinent to the problem. My client would be a Unity application that is posting web requests with sensitive information. I would like to protect against 1) This information being readable by anything but the server 2) This information being resent to (for example) inflate scores